# add bash so that it's recognized by /usr/bin/env

Tags: bash, shell, nixos, nix-shell

When I do `which bash` on NixOS, I get:

```
/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash
```

but I get this error:

> env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory

Which is surely because of the use of a hashbang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I tried this:

```
export PATH="/run/current-system/sw/bin:$PATH"
```

but that didn't help. Anyone know how I can get `env` to recognize the path to bash?

Comment: That `export` command should work.

Comment: Did you put it in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` so it's executed every time you login?

Comment: @Barmar: if `$PATH` was already an exported variable, which is often the case there wouldn't even been a need to re-export it

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk But there's no harm in re-exporting. My point was that assigning to `$PATH` should work, as long as he executes it every time he logs in.

Comment: Did you check the permissions and type of `/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash`?

Comment: Your issue could be related: [Github: Can't run stack setup on NixOS: ghc-pwd-bindist uses hard coded '/bin/bash'](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1857)

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, your shebang should actually work. I have written a bunch of ad hoc scripts in NixOS using this exact shebang with no issue. In fact this use case is the reason the devs put `env` in `/usr/bin` in the first place (no other binaries live there).

The fact that it's not working is strange, perhaps due to something in your system packages. Have you tried running `/usr/bin/env bash` from cmdline to see what happens?

As a side note, your `PATH` should already contain `/run/current-system/sw/bin` by default, if it doesn't you've got a bigger problem on your hands. This is where symlinks to all the software defined in your `configuration.nix` get installed.

**Workaround**

There is however a workaround to explicitly declare the full path directly to the bash binary if you need this to work right now and don't have time to figure out what the root cause is. You could wrap your script in a nix expression. Here is a simple `shell.nix` that gives you a symlink to a script residing in the nix-store that has the full path to bash in its shebang:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  script = pkgs.writeScript "myscript.sh" script_;

  script_ = ''
    #!${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash
    echo hello world
  '';
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  shellHook = ''
    ln -s ${script} myscript
  '';
}
```

This isn't the best solution, but it'll get you up and running right away. You could also do something very similar in your configuration.nix.

I would have recommended [nix-shell shebangs](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#use-as-a-interpreter) as a nicer solution, but since your original shebang isn't working, I figured this might be broken as well.